# NSDictionary sigbart

Tags: ios

i have some very strang behavior in iOS when using a NSMutableDictionary.
I am using the following code to access a dictionary from the app delegate.

```
self.dictTyp = appDelegate.dictTyp;
NSLog(@"%@", dictTyp);
NSArray *keys = [dictTyp allKeys];
```

The output of the NSLog is fine and it shows the content of the dictionary. but in the next line when i want to get allKeys i get an failure with unrecognized selector. can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong ?

thanks,
martin

Comment: Are you sure: 1. the app delegate's dictType variable is actually NSMutableDictionary, or NSDictionary  and 2. dictType has not been dealloced by the time it gets to your 3rd line? need more code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify NSLog to print out the type, too:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@", dictTyp, [dictType class]);
```

Check if dicType isn't a dictionary but something else. Then go back to where you created it and make sure it is actually created as a dictionary and that it is properly retained and not released too early.